# GetInterfaces in Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I created a project that uses `System.Reflection` namespace. Well, when I try use the method `GetInterfaces`, I see that it does not exist in the Windows Store.

I tried creating an extension method and I tried to use the rest of the methods to create a similar `GetInterfaces`, but I didn't have to.

Is there are a way to use `GetInterfaces` in Store Apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As first, I must say that this question is really simple and you just must know where to search.

For start, you must go to [.NET for Windows Store MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232(v=vs.120).aspx).

A little about reflection in .NET for Windows Store. Reflection is rewrited and was moved to `TypeInfo` class. The API, in which you are interested is located in [`TypeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.typeinfo.implementedinterfaces.aspx).

To get `TypeInfo` from specified class you must use [`GetTypeInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo.aspx) method, for that you must include namespace `System.Reflection`.

Example of code

```
using System.Reflection;

...
   var interfaces = typeof(string).GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces;
...
```

And, that's all. You can read more about reflection in WinRT here: [MSDN, `System.Reflection` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441595(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I searched before to post but I didn't get any post to asnwer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @jmmontero: no problems with that. As I said, `you just must know where to search`. When you don't know where to start search there is only one way to get info, in which you are interested - to ask in SO. So don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Some may find this to be simpler:

Use `Type.GetInterface(string name, bool ignoreCase)` instead of `Type.GetInterface(string name)`.

By default `GetInterface(string name)` does not ignoreCase so pass in false to keep the functionality the same.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up josilber!